# Is there a good reason that Setter.Value isn't a ContentProperty?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, setter, contentproperty

Every time I write out a setter whose `Value` property value isn't describable inline, I curse the fact that the API doesn't mark the `Setter` class with `[ContentProperty("Value")]`, which would allow this:

```
<Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
  <Setter.Value>
    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="#AAC" Opacity="0.2" GlowSize="1.25" />
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

...to be simplified to this:

```
<Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
  <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="#AAC" Opacity="0.2" GlowSize="1.25" />
</Setter>
```

So my question is kinda twofold.  Firstly, is there a good reason that the API hasn't been configured this way?  Secondly, is there anything stopping my making this metadata available to the `XamlReader` somehow, even though I don't control the WPF API?

Comment: Good point with the ContentProperty! 1up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point indeed... But you could easily create your own Setter class inherited from System.Windows.Setter, put the ContentProperty attribute on it, and use it instead of the standard Setter.

Answer (score 3):

Ten years and eighteen days after asking this question, the newly open-sourced WPF has a PR submitted that fixes this:

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/pull/745